# is this problem resolved? image view with folder reference

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

Anybody know a workaround for this problem described under:

"When you add the folder as a reference ("blue folder") it adds that folder to your bundle and not just the files in that folder. This means that when you want to reference a file in that folder, you have to reference it by doing foldername/myfile.png (because you have to dive into that folder, instead of just files in the root of the bundle).

I haven't found a way around this, so if you need to reference a file in a folder like that - be it in IB or a method like imageNamed: you need to do foldername/filename otherwise it won't be found."

It works when I create groups instead of folder references though.

Oh and I was wondering, if I add a folder with pictures in it with "Create groups for any added folders" selected, is all the structure going to be lost and everything will be on the root in my app bundle on the phone? Because if I go with the finder in my dev project, I can see that xcode copied my folder with all the pictures in it. But if it's true and no structure is kept, it means that I can't have two images with the same name in different folders in my dev project, correct? and even if all my images are in a folder "images" in my dev project, I still access them directly (foo.png not images/foo.png) in xcode, right?

**EDIT**

OK after adding the User paths (thanks to @Matthew Frederick) I can now see the filename of my images in the dropdown of IB and they show up on the interface! Problem is, it does not add the folder in the dropdown (I only see filename.png not images/filename.png), so when I compile, it looks for filename.png instead of "images/filename.png", so it does not work. I have to put images/filename.png manually in the IB dropdown, but then the image does not show in IB...

[image: Not show up with folder name]

[image: user paths]

Comment: Would you please include a brief description of the problem in your post here, in case that forum thread disappears for some reason?

Comment: I believe that you need to specify `/images` instead of `images`

Comment: @Matthew Frederick I tried both, does not work... Maybe I should use groups instead for my assets then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interface Builder will only look for potential graphics/media in your target's header search paths, so if you want access to anything that's not loose in your project folder you'll need to add those paths.

Fortunately it's easy.

- In the Project Navigator click on your project, and then in the main area click on your target.
- Click the **Build Settings tab** and scroll down to the **Search Paths section**.
- In the **User Header Search Paths** subsection double-click on the area in the Project column (3rd column over) and a small dialog will appear:

[image: Adding search paths]

- Click the **+** button, then type the path to your added folders, relative to the project's base folder, then click **Done**. The paths should be specified in the form of `/yourPathName`.

Poof, now IB can see the graphics inside the folder, and will present them as "folderName/imageName" in it's various dropdown menus and such.

**Note:** This is also true for .h and .m files and anything else inside a folder inside your project's folder: adding paths tells the compiler other places to look (hence the folders you see in my screenshot, "Human Data Classes" and "Machine Data Classes," where I keep my Core Data class files as created by [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator)).

Comment: also, is having your groups in different folders in the project dev works on the iphone too?

Comment: Yes, it works fine on the iPhone. You can build whatever file structure you want, as long as you add them all to your project correctly.

Comment: but if I "Create groups for any added folders", even if images are in different folders, I can't do [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo/bar.png"], for that I need to use folder references, correct?

Comment: Right. "Create groups" explicitly does **not** create folders: instead it tells Xcode to just put the files at the root of the bundle/app folder and to create a group, which is really just a convenient visual organization view.

Comment: Ok perfect, and do you have a workaround for the problem in my first post with the UIImageView (I corrected the forum link).

Comment: @all-R If you're referring to Interface Builder not being able to see graphics inside added true folders, I added that to my answer.